# Help identifying TV show/movie with disabled kid and angry father

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I don't know what spurred the curiosity about this, but a while back, maybe 10-15 years I saw a movie/show on TV (I feel like it was on Lifetime but I could be way off) where a disabled child and his father are in line at a grocery/convenience store.  The kid was probably a mid-teenaged boy, and his disability was like a stutter; he didn't talk well.  There was an incident in the store, where I think he was looking at someone but couldn't speak, and the person got perturbed by the child's stare and got angry and I think the dad got involved, hurt the man and then berated the kid.  The kid was visibly shaken and felt really bad.

Super random, I'm sorry but for whatever reason the scene will randomly pop into my head and I'd love to remember what it was from.

I remember the dad saying something like "why do you always do this" and making the kid feel bad.  Just got a really strong feeling of "dysfunctional" from the kid's family.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be completely off with this but this sounds like and episode of Touched By and Angel called 'An Angel on my Tree" (S07E10). The Episode included Chris Marquette.

I saw this forever ago but I distinctly remember a scene in this episode where the father and the son were in a convenience store/pharmacy and the son kept staring at a teenager and then he had a tic and started tappping the guy's shoulder. The teenager got upset and then an argument/fight ensued between the father and the teenager.

i hope this helps.

Comment: There's a [clip on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDwhWuCHi1A) with the father (later, in prison), if that helps. I understand the boy had Tourette's?

Comment: Yes, it was Tourette's (should probably have mentioned that shouldn't I). Yes, that is the exact clip I am talking about. Thank you for adding it.

Comment: Holy hell, you're a wizard.  Thank you so much! Great find.